# Restrict dynamic attributes declaration

Tags: python, attributes

`__slots__` declaration allows to restrict dynamic attributes declaration. But this is just one from a bunch of side effects of `__slots__`. How to restrict dynamic attributes declaration without `__slots__`?

Desired syntax:

```
class A(SomeSmrtClass):
    __allowed_attrs = set(['a', 'b'])
```

Desired behavior:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a = 1 # Allowed
>>> a.c = 2 # Allowed in SomeSmartClass by deault
>>> a.d = 3
AttributeError: ...
```

Comment: most common way is to override `__setattr__`. this is not an exact duplicate but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406363/setattr-versus-slots-for-constraining-attribute-creation-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Do you have an actual concern about extra attributes being added to an instance of `A`, or is this just a question about whether it is possible? As long as the methods of `A` only attempt to use `a` and `b`, it doesn't really matter if an instance acquires extra attributes.

Comment: Attributes aren't declared in Python, they're created on-the-fly. Overriding `__setattr__` is hardly sufficient to prevent that -- in fact it may be impossible. Therefore IMHO pursuing this goal is likely a waste of time.

Comment: I've seen things designed to do this sort of thing using metaclasses, proxy class interfaces, and `__setattr__`/`__getattribute__`, but they generally end up being fragile and messy.  You *can* do this, but you probably *shouldn't*.  Also, `__slots__` exists more for efficiency than for allowing statically defined interfaces.  What's your real problem here?  Upstream users of your classes fat fingering things and getting runtime errors?